# Is it possible to add a new module position within a module?

Tags: module, module-display, custom-module, positions

I know in a template you can add

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="newposition"   />
```

and then within the positions tags you add your new position.

```
<positions>
     <position>newposition</position>
</positions>
```

But I also know you can just create a position out of nowhere by typing it in the module back end in the position slot.

[image: Adding a new module position in the Joomla! module backend]

And then you can do module loadposition.

```
{loadposition some_position}
```

But if I echo this text in my module it's just text (a string).  If I echo the XML that's also a string, but I never expected that to work as it's not in the XML file.

Is it possible to add a module position within a module?

I'd rather do this the built in Joomla! way than using any extensions.

I have tried it with a content prepare plugin but I would rather try Sharky's method but I cannot get it working.  Here is what I have tried.

```
<?php 
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
?>

<div class="ui-nav ui-nav-mobile">
    <div class="g-content">
    <a class="ui-btn ui-menu-close">Close <i class="fa fa-close" aria-label="Close dialog"></i></a>        
    <?php
        foreach ($subform_items as $item) {
            $position_name = "{loadposition " . $item->position_name_x . "}";
         $modulePositions = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $position_name, '', 'mod_koy_sticky_contact.content');
            //$modulePositions = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->loadRenderer('modules')->render($position_name);
            echo "<div class='" . $item->position_name_x . "'>" . $modulePositions . "</div>";
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The commented out part shows a blank, but the other version works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using content plugin works, there is no need for it in PHP code. Instead you can use the document renderer directly:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

echo Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->loadRenderer('modules')->render($position);
```

Comment: Nice. Is `getDocument` still being used in J4? I should update my instance to use `HTMLHelper` instead of `JHtml`

Comment: `\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDocument()` works in J4 but is deprecated. Instead could use `\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()`. It works in J3 too.

Comment: What are the advantages of this verses my method?

Comment: Yours is better because it does it at core before the plugin?

Comment: My method doesn't run unneeded code.

Comment: I will update my code

Comment: Does this mean I should also do a pull request for mod_custom which does things my way?

Comment: No. `mod_custom` intends to trigger content plugins.

Comment: Was just about to delete my comment. Sorry being stupid.

Comment: I did this but it didn't work, it just echo's blank

Comment: Do you have some modules assigned to the position?

Comment: Yes, I simply changed the methodology.  My way works, your way comes out blank.  Not that I know anything, but I was wondering if it was right because I've never seen it written that way but it seems like you are getting, then rendering.  Should it be `set` at some point instead of `get`?  Also in your comment you write `\Joomla\CMS\Factory` but in the example you don't have `Joomla\CMS` could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe I need to create the position prior to rendering it?  Maybe that way works for positions that already exist?  Which is all done in the XML right?

Comment: No, it's a custom position. You just need to have some modules assigned to that position. Also make sure that menu assignment is configured. If it's set to `No Pages`, the modules will not appear.

Comment: But it works with the other code. So modules are definitely assigned to that position and page.

Comment: In which file are you placing the code? And have you adapted it to the rest of your code?

Comment: I updated the question so you can see more easily what I have attempted.

Comment: You are passing a shortcode (`$position_name`), not the position (`$item->position_name_x`) to `render()` call. Also, you can move `Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->loadRenderer('modules')` out of the loop.

Comment: Ah yes!  You are the man.  Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on specific circumstances. I have custom modules that contain several 'secondary' modules. I accomplish this using the Modules Anywhere extension and add {example module} to the code for the module I'm putting it in. You don't need to include a module position in the module settings to use Modules Anywhere.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/modules-anywhere/

Comment: Hmm, yes, I'm aware of that extension and it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I AM LEAVING THIS HERE IN CASE SOMEONE NEEDS TO KNOW HOW TO DO THIS.  BUT THE ANSWER ABOVE IS BETTER.

You need to switch on the content plugin

Trigger the onContentPrepare plugin event

https://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension

I ended up creating a Joomla! subform so I could add multiple positions.  Here is my code.

```
        foreach ($subform_items as $item) {
            $position_name = "{loadposition " . $item->position_name_x . "}";
            $modulePositions = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $position_name, '', 'mod_my_module.content');
            echo $modulePositions;
        }
```

What this is doing is:

1. A `foreach` on my XML to gain each position.
2. Use the usual `{loadposition yourPositionName}` code that can be seen here: https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F
3. Usually you would manually type it or use the Editor Module Plugin, in my example I used **yourPositionName**, but in real life I wanted these positions to come from my module where there is a repeatable field.  So I called `$position_name_x` which is part of the `params` of my `$item`.
4. I then echo my position name.  Without `content prepare` it will echo a literal string **{yourPositionName}** and not the modules in that position, but with `content prepare` it will send you the modules.  This is using the system plugin `onContentPrepare` I believe.

I hope that helps someone